# Get path in svg using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, svg

I have the following code which find all g's in svg, yet how could I get those path elements inside g's and their path value?

I am testing with this website: http://www.totalcorner.com/match/live_stats/57565755

related code:

```
nodes = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='all_container']/*[@id='highcharts-0']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']")
```

I have already tried this:

```
nodes = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='all_container']/*[@id='highcharts-0']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='path']")
```

yet what I get is something like this:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fb86fb35-d2fa-974a-af32-a15db1b7459d", element="{c1dad34f-764d-0249-9302-215dd9ae9cd8}")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fb86fb35-d2fa-974a-af32-a15db1b7459d", element="{a53816f4-9952-ab49-87ac-5d79538a855d}")>, ...]
```

How could I use this to find the path value?
thanks a lot

My updated solution:

thanks everyone's effort. After Robert Longson's updated answer, I think the following is the better solution:

```
nodes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='all_container']/*[@id='highcharts-0']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='path']")
for node in nodes:
    print(node.get_attribute("d"))
```

Since I cannot differentiate paths if using driver.find_elements_by_tag_name, I think the answer above is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a list, so try:

```
for node in nodes:
    print(node.text)
```

if a you are looking for a value of an attribute then use the following (`href` here as an example):

```
print(node.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: No, printing those node only give me sthg like this:
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fb86fb35-d2fa-974a-af32-a15db1b7459d", element="{c1dad34f-764d-0249-9302-215dd9ae9cd8}")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fb86fb35-d2fa-974a-af32-a15db1b7459d", element="{a53816f4-9952-ab49-87ac-5d79538a855d}")>, ...]

Comment: do you use the loop `for node in nodes:` ?

Answer (score 2):

[find_elements_by_tag_name](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html) can be used to find path children.

Once you have those, get_attribute("d") will get you the path value.

E.g.

```
for node in nodes:
    paths = node.find_elements_by_tag_name("path")
    for path in paths:
        value = path.get_attribute("d")
```

Comment: thx a lot, it works. only have to change this line:
    paths = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("path")
thx everyone's effort

Comment: That will find you all the paths whether or not they are children of g elements.